# Laravel Relationship with multiple table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm creating an online test portal.

The table structure is

1. live_test (To collect the different data of the test) - {id, title, instructions, total_questions, is_published, per_question_mark, per_question_negative_mark, duration}
2. questions (To store the questions) - {id, live_test_id, index, type, question, option_1, option_2, option_3, option_4, solution}
3. live_test_user (To find whether the user has already given the test or not) - {id, user_id, total_mark}
4. live_test_answers (To find out whether the user has given the right answer of the question or not - for later analytics) - {id, question_id, user_id, answer_given, is_correct}

This is working perfectly. I just want to know is there any relationship we can establish so that we can perform

```
$question->user->answer
```

or, something like,

```
$user->question->answer
```

To easily find that whether a user has given the correct answer for a particular question or not.

Each question will have only one entry in **live_test_answers** for **each user**.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships

Comment: I have read the documentation. There is nothing like that, I just wanted to know that is anyone have done this kind of relationship.

Comment: Read about [Eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) specifically under **Nested Eager Loading**

Comment: @apokryfos That need a relationship between models. That's what I'm asking is there any relationship can exists here. I will have the object of question and answer, I could easily do $answer = Question::where(['question_id' => $question_id, 'user_id' => $user_id])->first(); to find the given answer. I just want to know can any relationship exist here.

Comment: @apokryfos The live_test_answer table has both the id, user_id and question_id.

Comment: `live_test_answer` would be a pivot table relating users and questions e.g. in the user `$this->belongsToMany(Question::class, "live_test_answer")->withPivot("answer_given","is_correct")`

Comment: @apokryfos Yeah, it can be possible. Let me try with this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go through your `live_test_answers` table in order to get the answer and the question.

```
// For the example let's fetch the first answer the user gave
$answer = $user->answers()->first();
// Now let's fetch the question related to the answer
$question = $answer->question;

// Now you can check the answer for the question, something like
$isCorrect = $answer->answer == $question->answer;
```

Comment: Actually, I want to find the answer of given question. Your answer has opposite flow.

Comment: You can query an answer by question id and user id `$answer = Answer::where('user_id', $userId)->where('question_id')->first()`

Comment: $answer = Question::where(['question_id' => $question_id, 'user_id' 
=> $user_id])->first(); , This is working fine, as I have mentioned in the question. I just wanted to know that, is there any relationship can exist here, so I can play with the objects..